# How to perform Sorting using flow steps in WebMethods (Software AG)?

Tags: sorting, webmethods

I am new to this Middleware and I tried my level best to perform sorting using the flow steps in designer but couldn't make it.Can anybody help me out by giving me direction for how to complete my work?(like the flow steps in order and where i can put the conditions and all)

Thanks.

Comment: I started the flow with Map and continued by putting the Loop and Branch...Since I am new to this..I dont know where to put or initialize the looping variables and all..I dont know how to insert the condition for the same...Please help me by directing me the flow of the flow steps...

Answer (score 2):

No need to over-complicate it - use the utilities - **pub.document:sortDocuments** is what you are looking for.

- *If* you receive *stringList* as input - convert this into a *documentList*. This can be done using **pub.list:stringListToDocumentList** (set the key to 'value')
- Use **pub.document:sortDocuments** to sort the *documentList*. Remember to specify the key as 'value' once again and *compareStringAs* as 'numeric'. The order can also be set (ascending/descending)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to Sort? For Document-Lists you will find a built-in services in the WmPublic Folder.
For String-Lists i would use a Java-Service for Sorting.

Comment: Hi..Simple sorting..like bubble sort...we need to sort 10 numbers using flow service..not java service..Can you please explain me the flow for that?i have tried with both sequence and repeat..but i haven't got the output..

Answer (score 0):

Logic behind Sorting in webMethods is same as all other languages. You need LOOP to iterate every string in stringList, BRANCH to compare the two number and then map to the compare result to new StringList.

Comment: Yes true..But when i applied sorting logic,its not working..may be mapping issues or may be i have given conditions incorrectly...Since i m new to this technology,i need a help to reach my solution..

Answer (score 0):

What format do you have the numbers in? Are they in a flat file or in a string list etc.